# Ada: constant declaration

Tags: floating-point, constants, ada

I'm reading Norman Cohen's Ada 95 book and on page 129 we have the constant declarations:

```
 Pi: constant Float := 3.1415926536
```

and

```
Pi: constant := 3.1415926536
```

The second declaration is said to be interpreted as, I quote: "any floating-point of fixed-point type with the appropriate range". My question is say one is working with Long_Float precision, then for example to declare a constant say 2*PI do one has to specifically declare like

```
Two_Pi : CONSTANT Long_Float := 2.0 * 3.1415926536
```

or much better still:

```
Two_Pi: CONSTANT Long_Float :=  2.0 * Ada.Numerics.Pi;
```

(the second declaration to take advantage of more digits after the decimal point) ?

Would

```
Two_Pi : CONSTANT := 2.0 * 3.1415926536
```

or better still

```
Two_Pi: CONSTANT  :=  2.0 * Ada.Numerics.Pi;
```

be as good as the book claims so that the Ada compiler would know for instance if I'm using Two_Pi in a Long_Float calculation, then the compiler would supply the required number of precision digits? Since the Pi value 3.1415926536 is not of Long_Float type (as it has fewer precision digits), I guess that the last declaration i.e.

```
Two_Pi: CONSTANT  :=  2.0 * Ada.Numerics.Pi;
```

would be all that is required if I need Two_Pi in a Long_Float calculation. Am I understanding right? With a similar understanding, then

```
Two_Pi: CONSTANT  :=  2.0 * Ada.Numerics.Pi;
```

would be relevant also in a Float type calculation and the compiler would supply only the required number of precision digits.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Number Declarations`](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-3-2.html) such as

```
Two_Pi : constant := 2.0 * Ada.Numerics.Pi;
```

are sometime called *named numbers*. Such a number is [*universal*](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-4-1.html) "in that it is acceptable where some particular type in the class is expected (see [8.6](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-8-6.html))."

Addendum: Because such numbers are [*universal*](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-4-1.html), they can "be used as operands with the primitive subprograms of any type in the corresponding class." For example, `Two_Pi` can be multiplied by `Float`, `Long_Float` or any type derived from *universal_real*.

On a related note, you might like this Ada [binding](http://code.google.com/p/adabindinggmpmpfr/) to the GNU GMP and MPFR libraries.

Addendum: The binding allows one to use the GNU libraries from Ada, as seen in this [example](http://code.google.com/p/adabindinggmpmpfr/source/browse/trunk/mpfr_example.adb).

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly then I don't need to add the Long_Float. The expression that you gave is sufficient for the compiler to know what precision to use.

Comment: I use the GNAT GPL compiler from Adacore. If I understand correctly then this GNU GMP and MPFR numerical libraries are for GCC only. Am I right?

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Yes and no, respectively; see above.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Oops, I misunderstood the second question. I know the binding works with GNAT, but it should also work with other compilers that support linking with GCC binaries.

Comment: Thanks. So it's yes for the first and yes/no for the second :). I shall try to check if this binding works with GNAT from Adacore.